# Angular ng-init fails to assign with html elemets

Tags: php, angularjs, quotes

I have a administration corner on my web, where can Admin create and post news.
It's implemented with html alements as helper. Admin clics on buttons and elements helps him, to style his text.
It looks this:
[image]

I have an option to Edit existing News as well.
Problem is if I try to assign this html text into my variable in ng-init
It all go bad.

```
<h4 ng-init="TextAreaText = '<?php if ($_GET["NID"]) $Admin->DrawNewsByID($_GET["NID"]) ?>'"> Editor </h4>
```

It means if there is NewsID in Get, It selects News text in php and tries to assign it into `TextAreaText` varible.

But it is shown like this:
[image]

Because of my bad quotation marks.
As you can see: - source code from my browser
[image]

Is it possible to samehow fix it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you trying to put html code inside ng-init?

Comment: What if there is no NID value in $_GET?  For example have you tried `if (isset($_GET["NID"]))`?

Comment: Pedro, Yes, I'm trying.
David, nothing is returned. Admin can create a new one.